# htaccess opening php files as downloads

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, plesk

i have had a search around but haven't been able to find a similar problem.

When i add the following to my htaccess file (i want to restrict upload types to my server)

```
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment

<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(doc?x|txt|xls?x|csv|pdf|ppt?x|zip|gif|jpe?g|png)$">
ForceType none
Header unset Content-Disposition
</FilesMatch>

Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

I then refresh my page it then opens the download dialog box instead of showing the php page. I though it might be the deflate mod compressing the htaccess onto 1 line but im not so sure now.

could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is saying treat any file except the following as a download. php is not in the list, so it is downloaded. Also, this has nothing to do with uploads

Comment: Why are you doing this via htaccess?

Comment: aaaaah! you are right sorry its been a long day and i should have realised that. @LiamSorsby i am checking file types with my js, php and htaccess to make sure everything is as it should be when uploaded. Have you got a better suggestion?

i just presumed that as SetHandler application/x-httpd-php was breaking my site in the <FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$"> that it was the FilesMatch that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above i have sorted the problem. it was my mistake